# MediaController Play On Video Click

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a simple app where a video loads from a url and when you click on the video, the MediaController pops up.

This works fine, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can just skip that step and have it so that clicking the video automatically triggers the 'play' function of the MediaController without having to ever see it.

These videos are short and I don't need to be able to control them other than just pressing play.

Here is my code:

```
private static final String MOVIE_URL ="http://mywebsite.com/videos/testvideo.mkv";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(MOVIE_URL);
    vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vid.setVideoURI(video);
    vid.seekTo(1);
    vid.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view)
                {
                    vid.start();
                    vid.requestFocus();
                }
            }
        );


}
```

**EDIT**

I needed to use onTouchListener instead of onClickListener because it's a videoview. This works perfectly!

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final VideoView vid = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    Uri video = Uri.parse(MOVIE_URL);
   // vid.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    vid.setVideoURI(video);
    vid.seekTo(1);

    vid.setOnTouchListener(
            new View.OnTouchListener()
            {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                       vid.start();
                        vid.requestFocus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        );

}
```

Comment: What's the problem with your code?  If you don't want the MediaController then don't call `setMediaController`, but other than that it looks fine.

Comment: This posted code works. Clicking the VideoView brings up the MediaController and then I click play. I'm wondering if I can skip the step where I press play on the MediaController by somehow telling the MediaController to automatically start the video when I click on the VideoView. Basically I just don't to have to click on 2 things to play the video)

Comment: When I remove the setMediaController line, the video doesn't start playing when I click on the videoview.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `PreparedListener` to listen for video if prepared . When the `VideoView` is prepared to `start` the play

```
  vid.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            vid.start();
            vid.requestFocus();
        }
    });
  vid.setVideoURI(video);
```

When `setVideoURI`, the instance of `MediaPlayer`will be created  and register for `MediaPlayer` `setOnPreparedListener` . So that when `MediaPlayer` is prepared the  `VideoView` `onPrepared` listener will get called.

Comment: Does this work with the onclick function or is this replacing that portion?